# Redirect users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I have a job show page where I want only sign users to apply and if user is not sign in I will show him the apply button and when they click in the button they will redirected to the sign up page and after sign up they will redirected to the job show page. I'm wondering how can I achieve this?
I was thinking to separate the job into 2 model job-details and job_apply and in the job_apply controller put this `before_action :authenticate_user!`, but I'm wondering if there another solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another action. Don't add `before_action :authenticate_user!` for the show action.

You need to add `before_action :authenticate_user!` for the `apply` action. once the non-signed in user clicks the `apply` action, He/She will be redirected to sign_in.

Comment: apply is just a string field in my job model

Comment: Well, the correct flow is that you add an action `apply`. And leave the Show as is since its the same for both guest and logged in users.

Comment: so your idea is to add a apply action in the job controller? if so what will be in this action??

Answer (score 0):

I just use a helper method in application controller.  This code obviously needs a current_user helper method as well.

```
 def confirm_logged_in
    if !current_user
      redirect_to '/sessions/new'
      flash[:login_failure] = 'You must be logged in to see this page'
      session[:return_path] = request.original_url
    end
  end
```

then in your sessions controller use something like

```
redirect_to session[:return_path] || root_path
```